# Compressing server into .jar file

Tags: terminal

Currently I'm attempting to compress a decompressed jar file that I have changed into a jar file. How can I do this via the command line? I know that there is a `jar` command in terminal, I'm just having trouble learning how to compress that folder.

If the folder's directory (probably not correct term, but hopefully you get the idea) is `/Users/Odinulf/folderone/foldertwo` (foldertwo is directory that I want compressed), what would be the exact code to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Odinulf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd /Users/Odinulf/folderone
jar cvf myjar.jar foldertwo
```

For example:

```
/Users/ian/code/tmp [ian@Ian-Cs-MacBook-Pro] [19:13]
> jar cvf myjar.jar 8779 
added manifest
adding: 8779/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: 8779/.DS_Store(in = 6148) (out= 355)(deflated 94%)
adding: 8779/logs/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: 8779/logs/MasterLog.txt(in = 3044043) (out= 207357)(deflated 93%)
adding: 8779/logs/StartLog.txt(in = 6984480) (out= 685836)(deflated 90%)
/Users/ian/code/tmp [ian@Ian-Cs-MacBook-Pro] [19:13]
> ls *.jar
myjar.jar
```

Breaking it down, the options are:

- `c` - create a jar file
- `v` - be verbose when you do it
- `f` - put the bitstream in to a file instead of standard out

Then you give it the file to put the bitstream in to. In this case `myjar.jar`. And then you give it a list of directories and files to put in to that jar bitstream. Relative and absolute pathing for contents is generally maintained so be careful with that.

Comment: Just another quick question: I get this error when I try to open the jar `Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from [jar file path]`

Comment: Googled it quickly... got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591516/why-its-failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-from-jar-file - got any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a manifest.txt file for your Jar file according to the to answer in that SO question you found. That'd be a Java question and it's veering in to off-topic for Ask Different.

Comment: Update: I just used `jar cvfm`, and it worked fantastically. Thanks for your help :D